# Birt Report Calling multiple times

Tags: java, birt

I am very new in birt reporting,Give me a proper solution for my problem.I am Generating a report(.pdf) using birt tool,in which user select the employee by check box and report for that employee is generated. now ,problem is that function getemployeeData() which fetch the employee data
calling multiple times even if i select the one employee, I try hard but not get a proper solution.
         I am describing my problem using code below.

**script function which calling multiple times**

```
 count=0;
 objBIRTController = contractandInvoice.model.BIRTConnection();     
 month=params["monthId"].value;
 year=params["year"].value;
 empId=params["empId"].value;
 listMainData= objBIRTController.**getemployeeData**(month,year,empId);

Here getemployeeData() is calling multiple times.
```

**In fecth** where listMainData data is iterated.

```
   if(count < listMainData.size()){
   row["empName"] = listMainData.get(count).getEmpName();
   row["DOJ"] = listMainData.get(count).getDOJ();
   row["empCode"] = listMainData.get(count).getEmpCode();       
   count++;
   return true;
```

}

return false;

**BirtConnection.java**

```
public List<EmployeeDataVO> getemployeeData(String monthId1,
        String yearId1, String empId1) {

       In this method I am retriving list which contains the employee data.

     }
```

Comment: can you expand what you mean by "calling multiple times even if i select the one employee": how many times is it called per report execution? Is it always called with the expected employeeID? Does the report still render as expected despite of this issue?

Comment: I mean to say if i select one employee getemployeeData that i have mention is called only one times,If i select two employee it is two times,Here even if i select only one employee getemployeeData function called multiple times,I meant to say getemployeeData goes in looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first script is the "open" method of the underlying scripted dataset, it is triggered as many times as this dataset is invoked during report execution. For example:

- if a table using this dataset is nested in an outer table, "open" method will be invoked for each row of the outer table.
- if we insert dataset fields  into a grid by dragging one by one each field from the control panel onto the grid(which would be a very, very bad way to design reports), "open" method would be triggered **for each data field**.

For a better understanding: create a new blank report , copy your 3 report parameters and the dataset into it and add a new table just by dragging the whole dataset from the control panel onto the report body. Then run this new report and you will notice "getemployeeData"  is invoked only once, because the dataset is bound to only one report element (the table).

Attach a .rptdesign sample if you need  more explanations about this.

Comment: Hi i have solved this problem by adding all parameter in HasMAP in onfetch event i created map and put report component on it and retrieve each component onfetch event based on key